# What is the significance of the temporary key file in an add-in project?

Tags: visual-studio, pfx

When I create a new add-in to Outlook using VS10 (and most likely even other version as well), I see that the IDE has created a file for me: `OutlookAddIn1_TemporaryKey.pfx`.

It's openable with Crypto Shell Extensions and as far I recall I haven't checked for anything that has to do with any cryptography. Can I remove it safely?

In the same directory I also have `OutlookAddIn1_1_TemporaryKey.pfx`, which makes me suspect that the helping hand of VS10 has got confused. I understand that VS likes creating a bunch of files to control the situation and I can live with that. Having said that, I wonder if I need to e.g. version control or distribute those PFX-files. What's up with that?